# select tag with ng-model not showing the correct option

Tags: angularjs

So this is my code:

```
<select ng-model="institution.data_collection" class="form-control" required>
  <option value="" disabled>Please Select</option>
  <option value="109">24 Hours</option>
  <option value="107" onselect="">School Hours</option>
</select>
```

`institution.data_collection` value is equal to `109` and I expected the option `24 Hours` to be selected since it has a value of `109`. But what happens is I find a new option added in the select tag:

`<option value="? number:109 ?"></option>`

Going through SO questions I find that most people defined the `options` in an array in the controller which may be the better practice in that case and would solve my issue, however, I still want to understand what is happening.

Comment: remove `ng-selected` from 109, yes using array form select is better option ..

Comment: @atulquest93 I was trying out a different solution and forgot that there, but i doesn't have any affect on the current scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the $scope variable in the controller

```
$scope.institution ={};
$scope.institution.data_collection = '109';
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ListCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.institution ={};
    $scope.institution.data_collection = '109';
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
   <select ng-model="institution.data_collection" class="form-control" required>
  <option value="" disabled>Please Select</option>
  <option value="109" ng-selected="">24 Hours</option>
  <option value="107" onselect="">School Hours</option>
</select>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That worked, so you think the issue is that the $scope.institution.data_collection is a number and the value in the options tags are strings?

Comment: Thanks. It worked when I parsed it to a string like so: $scope.institution.data_collection = $scope.institution.data_collection.toString();

Answer (score 1):

Make `$scope.institution.data_collection = "109"`, it must work. Any HTML element sets its value as string not as a number by default, so you will need to assign string value to its model to work fine. Other option is to use ng-options, then you will be able to assign numeric value as model.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select ng-model="institution.data_collection" ngChange="expression()" class="form-control" required>
  <option value="?">Please Select</option>
  <option value="109">24 Hours</option>
  <option value="107">School Hours</option>
</select>
```

You should not write "onselect" for option, you have to assign that attribute to select tag.

Script :

```
$scope.expression = function (){
 $scope.institution // selected value
// write your logic here
}
```